# Find unique or duplicate values between two worksheets

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I have multiple worksheets with the results from various searches on a database.  I'd like to compare them to find any unique hits (or duplicates if that's easier).  Each worksheet has the same column headings but the data in the rows may or may not be different and may be in a different order.  For example, if Search1 finds ROGER and ROGER is on row 27, and I compare that with the result of Search2, which finds ROGER but puts him on row 6, I'd like a method that would know that row 6 and 27 are the same data even though the position is different.

Answer (score 0):

I’ll assume, for simplicity, that your search results
(the ones you’re talking about) are in Column `A` on both sheets,
starting on Row 1. 
In some other column on Sheet1, insert the formula

```
=MATCH(A1, Sheet2!A$1:A$20, 0)
```

and likewise insert

```
=MATCH(A1, Sheet1!A$1:A$20, 0)
```

on Sheet2. 
(Adjust the `20` to an upper bound
for the number of rows of data that you have,
or simply replace `A$1:A$20` with `A:A`.)

This takes the result from Column `A` on the current row
(on the current sheet)
and searches for it in Column `A` on the other sheet. 
It returns the row number of the first match, or `#N/A` if there’s no match.

[image: screen shot of Sheets 1 and 2]

Of course, if you don’t want to see the error codes, you can use

```
=IFERROR(MATCH(A1, Sheet2!A:A, 0), "")
```

and/or use conditional formatting to highlight the duplicates.